# creating a web image tiler

Tags: image-processing, tiling

I need to show a rather large image that represents something similar to a construction plan and allow users to place pins on it.

I'd like to do this similarly to how google maps works having the image tiled so the user can zoom in and get a better resolution if needed, as these images can be quite large its quite likely they would want to zoom in pretty far.

I'm considering the best way to do this, the images that would be used would not be a constant size although they would be roughly in the same ballpark say roughly around 3000-4000 x 3000-4000 pixels and they are not neccessarily a square shape.

I am trying to figure out the best way to tile this, I don't know if I can really set a tile size (say like 256px like google maps) and use that as its quite possible that some of the tiles wont fit 256px. I guess I could add tranparency/whitespace to make up the difference or I could alter the entire image before any tiling is completed and add transparency/whitespace to the whole image to make it a square.

I've also considered just defining a certain number of tiles to split the image into, eg. 3 tiles wide by 4 high or similar and just calculate on the fly the required size of the tile, at least this way I think there shouldn't be any transparency fill needed.

Can anyone suggest any pitfalls or other ways to go about this?

I would just use google maps but it doesnt quite suit what I am doing as these points would be located in something like a house where it would be too fine-grained to use gis points.

Comment: This can help you with the blending possibilites - check out the last chapter http://graphics.cs.cmu.edu/courses/15-463/2004_fall/www/Papers/MSR-TR-2004-92-Sep27.pdf